# Query using a date range but end date may be null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

sql server 2014

I am trying to query data using a date range.  Data in the table is datetime datatype.

so I want to use as parameters `@IncidentDate` and `@IncidentEndDate`.

Issues are that the `@IncidentEndDate` may be null. Also each row in the data may or may not have an end_datetime (null if no date)

In my where clause I have

```
(end_datetime IS NULL) AND (@IncidentDate >= CAST(start_datetime AS DATE) AND @IncidentDate <= DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,start_datetime)))
OR
(@IncidentDate <= end_datetime) AND (@IncidentEndDate >= start_datetime)
```

However I am not sure if this si working properly.  I would expect rows that have no end_datetime to appear in the results but they don't seem to be .

**EDIT: In the end I came up with the following after reading everybody's replies...**

```
WHERE (
      @IncidentDate <= isnull(end_datetime, dateadd(day,1,start_datetime))
   ) 
   AND (
   isnull(@IncidentEndDate,dateadd(day,1,@IncidentDate)) >= start_datetime
   )
```

This seems to me to be a tidier way to satisfy my requirements - it looks after the possiblity of both `end_datetime` being null and `@IncdidentEndDate` being Null

Comment: show us sample data and expected result.

Comment: There's an order of precedence between AND and OR. Use parens to specify a different order of evaluation.

Comment: Is `(@IncidentDate >= CAST(start_datetime AS DATE) AND @IncidentDate <= DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,start_datetime)))` really an [unSARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) way to write `( @IncidentDate <= Start_DateTime and Start_DateTime < DateAdd( day, 1, @IncidentDate ) )`, i.e. any `Start_DateTime` that occurs on `@IncidentDate` regardless of time-of-day? (I'm assuming that `@IncidentDate` is a `Date` since the question is unclear.)

Comment: @IncidentDate is going to be a Datetime but will always be midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can use the ISNULL() function to help handle NULL values.  The ISNULL() function checks the value and, if it's NULL, replaces it with a supplied value.  So if you wanted the NULLs, you could put in a value that would match or, if not, something that would definitely be outside your range like 01/01/1900 or the MIN Date (varies depending on DATETIME or DATETIME2).

To exclude:

`SELECT * FROM mySweetTable WHERE ISNULL(createdDate, '01-JAN-1900') >= '01-JAN-2015'`

To include:

`SELECT * FROM mySweetTable WHERE ISNULL(createdDate, GETDATE()) >= '01-JAN-2015'`

Although, I don't recommend ACTUALLY leaving GETDATE() in the WHERE clause, that's bad news bears; replace it with a variable or specific value.

Comment: In the end the suggestion to use ISNULL helped me the most. I have edited the original post to show my final version of the where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
--This should get you what you want

start_datetime >= @IncidentDate and (@IncidentEndDate is null or end_datetime is null or end_datetime < dateadd(day,1,@IncidentEndDate))
```

Unless, of course, you want to exclude ones where the `end_datetime is null` and if that's the case just let me know!

Comment: You probably want remove `@IncidentEndDate is null or ` , if that is null left side will be unknown.